# Run call Glad in CMake

Tags: python, linux, bash, cmake

I'm trying to run the python module [glad](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad) from within a CMakeList.txt using [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html#command:execute_process).

Following the instructions on [glad's](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad) git hub page, I installed it using:

```
pip install --user glad
```

When I run the following command in a terminal emulator with bash it works as expected:

```
python -m glad --generator=c --no-loader --out-path=GL
```

The same holds for:

```
/home/boris/miniconda2/bin/python -m  glad --generator=c --no-loader --out-path=GL
```

But when I run the following CMakeList.txt it reports, that the module glad could not be found.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
set (glad_arg "-m glad --generator=c --no-loader --out-path=GL")
set (glad_cmd "python")

message(STATUS "glad cmd: ${glad_cmd}")
execute_process(COMMAND ${glad_cmd} ${glad_arg}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
  RESULT_VARIABLE glad_result
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE glad_ver
  ERROR_VARIABLE glad_err)
message(STATUS "glad_err: ${glad_err}")
```

Output when running ../cmake from within the build directory of my project:

```
boris-> cmake ..
-- glad cmd: python
-- glad_err: /home/boris/miniconda2/bin/python: No module named  glad --generator=c --no-loader --out-path=GL

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/boris/Projects/OpenGL/SO/1_glad_In_Cmake/build
```

Question: Why is it not working, and how to fix it?

Comment: Do **not put all parameters** into double quotes. Correct: `set (glad_arg -m glad --generator=c --no-loader --out-path=GL)`. (That is, double quotes normally may be completely omitted).

Comment: @Tsyvarev, this solved the problem. Thank you very much. Just copy and past your comment, post it as answer, and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.
Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of `glad_arg` variable contains **single** value, as you incorporate it into double quotes:

```
set (glad_arg "-m glad --generator=c --no-loader --out-path=GL") # Single value variable
```

Because of that, CMake interpret `${glad_arg}` as **single function parameter** when you pass it to `execute_process()`. So, when *COMMAND* is called, it takes whole content of `glad_arg` as **single command line argument**.

Correct way for defining list of *COMMAND*'s arguments is CMake lists. Simply remove double quotes:

```
set (glad_arg -m glad --generator=c --no-loader --out-path=GL) # Variable with list of values.
```

---

Most of CMake commands works with **lists** and don't require double quotes around the whole value.

The most notable exception is `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` / `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variables, which should be *space-separated strings* (thus double quotes are really needed).